# Excel 2013 Overflow due to lack of VBA optimization

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I would like to export data from a consolidated sheet (DATA) to multiple sheets regarding criteria.
I have a total of 13 criteria, each criteria has to be exported in its dedicated sheet.

I'm trying to optimize this macro (only 2 criteria here) because it lag out

```
Sub copy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim feuillePrincipale As Worksheet
Dim S01Sheet As Worksheet
Dim S02Sheet As Worksheet
Set feuillePrincipale = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Set S01Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S01")
Set S02Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S02")

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name = "S01" Then
i = 2
j = 2
    While Not IsEmpty(feuillePrincipale.Cells(i, 1))
        If feuillePrincipale.Cells(i, 11).Value Like "S01*" Then
        feuillePrincipale.Cells.Rows(i).EntireRow.copy S01Sheet.Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Wend
 End If

If sh.Name = "S02" Then
i = 2
j = 2
    While Not IsEmpty(feuillePrincipale.Cells(i, 1))
        If feuillePrincipale.Cells(i, 11).Value Like "S02*" Then
        feuillePrincipale.Cells.Rows(i).EntireRow.copy S02Sheet.Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Wend
End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you have any idea, I read I can use Advanced filter but as you guess I'm new in VBA so I'm listening any tips!

Comment: yes, you should use an autofilter and use a special select to get only the visible cells.  If you want the loop method, you should loop through each row on sheets("DATA") and use a `Select Case` Statement to decide onto which sheet the data is placed.   By looping through each sheet you are adding loops that will slow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Advanced Filter method you asked for:

```
Public Sub Christophe()

    Const FILTER_COLUMN = 11

    Dim i&, rCrit As Range, rData As Range, aShts

    aShts = ["SO"&row(1:13)]

    Set rData = Sheets("DATA").[a1].CurrentRegion
    Set rCrit = rData.Resize(2, 1).Offset(, rData.Columns.Count + 2)
    rCrit(1) = rData(1, FILTER_COLUMN)

    For i = 1 To UBound(aShts)
        rCrit(2) = aShts(i, 1) & "*"
        rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, Sheets(aShts(i, 1)).[a1].Resize(, rData.Columns.Count)
    Next

    rCrit.Clear

End Sub
```

The execution time should be instantaneous.

Note: this assumes that you do have 13 criteria, each starting with "SO" and that they occupy column 11 of the Data sheet. It also assumes that you already have 13 sheets named SO1... SO13 in the workbook.

**UPDATE**

Based on new information that the pattern of the criteria can change, please try this version instead. Note, that it assumes that the sheets already exist and that the sheet names match the criteria:

```
Public Sub Christophe()

    Const FILTER_COLUMN = 11

    Dim i&, rCrit As Range, rData As Range, aShts

    aShts = Array("SO1", "SO2", "ADQ03", "LocS10")

    Set rData = Sheets("DATA").[a1].CurrentRegion
    Set rCrit = rData.Resize(2, 1).Offset(, rData.Columns.Count + 2)
    rCrit(1) = rData(1, FILTER_COLUMN)

    For i = 0 To UBound(aShts)
        rCrit(2) = aShts(i) & "*"
        rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, Sheets(aShts(i)).[a1].Resize(, rData.Columns.Count)
    Next

    rCrit.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm gonna try the best way to know.
Unfortunately I have already my sheets prepared but the criteria name change, I have 'S02' 'S02' but then 'ADQ03' or 'LocS10'  so I have to adapt (otherwise it would be no fun right ?) your code. I think here :
aShts = ["SO"&row(1:13)] need to be modified ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to modify. That was a shortcut based on the information given in your example. I will update the code now.

Comment: One question... Are you saying that the criteria and the sheet names do NOT match? For example, your criteria are SO1, SO2, SO3, etc. and your sheet names that the relevant data needs to be deposited into are (for example) SO1, ADQ03, Locs10?

Comment: Or, are you saying the criteria and their relevant sheet names DO match but that they just do not all start with SO?

Comment: The criteria and the sheet are matching

Comment: Just extend the array at the top to include all of your criteria.

Comment: Yeah seems to work Excel Hero thanks for your supporting !

Answer (score 1):

Try using an array to set your criteria sheets:

```
Dim shArray           As Variant
Dim shArrayString     As String
Dim feuillePrincipale As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i                 As Long
Dim j                 As Long

Set feuillePrincipale = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

j = 1

'// Create array and populate
shArray = Array("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04") '// add as required

'// Create string representation of array
shArrayString = "{"""
For i = LBound(shArray) To UBound(shArray)
    shArrayString = shArrayString & shArray(i) & ""","""
Next    
shArrayString = Left(shArrayString, Len(shArrayString) - 2) & "}"

'//Start loop    
    With feuillePrincipale
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Not Evaluate("ISERROR(MATCH(" & Left(.Cells(i, 11), 3) & "," & shArrayString & ",0))") Then
                .Rows(i).Copy Sheets(shArray(WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(.Cells(i, 11), 3), shArray, 0))).Cells(j, 1)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

It's a bit unclear because if you follow the code you've posted - it's actually just copying and pasting data to the same sheet...

Comment: I may be wrong but it appears that he is copying from `sheets("DATA")` and pasting it to the various sheets based on what is in column A of `sheets("DATA")`.  I like your answer though very clean and easier to add new sheets.  I will definitely incorporate your method in my personal future codes.

Comment: Yep, you're right I'm wrong - I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: Ah I was also confusing, then I'm waiting your edit because I'm still lost @Scott actually column K
Thanks for replying

Comment: Thanks Macro I'm gonna run it and see what's happen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use an autofilter and use a special select to get only the visible cells.

If you want the loop method, you should loop through each row on sheets("DATA") and use a Select Case Statement to decide onto which sheet the data is placed.

By looping through each sheet you are adding loops that will slow it down.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim cel As Range

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim feuillePrincipale As Worksheet
Dim S01Sheet As Worksheet
Dim S02Sheet As Worksheet
Set feuillePrincipale = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Set S01Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S01")
Set S02Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S02")

For Each cel In feuillePrincipale.Range(feuillePrincipale.Range("A1"), feuillePrincipale.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    Select Case Left(cel.offset(,10).value, 3)
        Case "S01"
            j = S01Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            feuillePrincipale.Cells.Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.copy S01Sheet.Rows(j)
        Case "S02"
            j = S02Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            feuillePrincipale.Cells.Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.copy S02Sheet.Rows(j)
        'Case ....  keep adding select statement till you get to the last condition
        Case Else
    End Select
Next cel

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: I will leave this answer here but either of the answers Macro Man or Excel Hero gave are better and will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks scott ! appreciate your support